# Javascript - Splitting number variable as a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Having some issues getting my head around this. I am trying to use a function to  split a variable into two and then add a html `<span>` tag around each character. 
I have managed to do this process through a variable easy enough however when I try as a function it does not work.

```
<script>
var value = "30";

function myFunction(a) {
    var a = a.split("", 2);
    var a = "<span>" + a[0] + "</span><span>" a[1] + "</span>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(value);</script>
```

Any hints as to why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

- You have to return a value from the function
- You missed one `+` in the `"<span>" + a[0] + "</span><span>" a[1] + "</span>"` line
- If you want to split a word at every character, use empty quotation marks as the argument
- You have used three `a` variables, overwriting each of them when declaring the new one

```js
var value = "30";

function myFunction(a) {
    var b = a.split('');
    return "<span>" + a[0] + "</span><span>" + a[1] + "</span>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(value);
```

```html
<p id='demo'></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since strings are arrays, you can do this:

```js
var test = "1234";

function wrapSpans(a) {
    var tempStr = "";
    var x = 0;
    while(x < a.length) {
        tempStr += `<span>${a[x]}</span>`;
        x++;
    }
    return tempStr;
}

var value = "30";

document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = wrapSpans(test);
```

```css
span {
  padding: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 2px;
}

div {
  padding: 2px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing the `+` operator in the line
   `var a = "<span>" + a[0] + "</span><span>" a[1] + "</span>";`

   It should be

   `var a = "<span>" + a[0] + "</span><span>" + a[1] + "</span>";`
2. You need to return a value from the function.
3. No need to redefine the `var a` again and again.

```js
var value = "30";

function myFunction(a) {
    var a = a.split("", 2);
    a = "<span>" + a[0] + "</span><span>" + a[1] + "</span>";
    return a;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(value);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```